# Regex for removing only specific special characters from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, special-characters

I'd like to write a regex that would remove the special characters on following basis:

- To remove white space character
- `@`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`,  `<`,  `>` or `#`

I have written this regex which removes whitespaces successfully:

```
 string username = Regex.Replace(_username, @"\s+", "");
```

But I'd like to upgrade/change it so that it can remove the characters above that I mentioned.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 string username = Regex.Replace(_username, @"(\s+|@|&|'|\(|\)|<|>|#)", "");
```

Comment: Hi,
How can I replace dots, commas, and dashes

Comment: Hi @Harendrra, you can use: 
`string username = Regex.Replace(_username, @"([\.,-])", "");`

Answer (score 11):

use a character set `[charsgohere]`

```
string removableChars = Regex.Escape(@"@&'()<>#");
string pattern = "[" + removableChars + "]";

string username = Regex.Replace(username, pattern, "");
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using *Linq* instead of *regular expressions*:

```
 string source = ...

 string result = string.Concat(source
   .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && 
                c != '(' && c != ')' ...));
```

In case you have *many* characters to skip you can organize them into a collection:

```
 HashSet<char> skip = new HashSet<char>() {
   '(', ')', ... 
 };

 ... 

 string result = string.Concat(source
   .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !skip.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: Why is Linq better than regex?

Comment: Linq is simpler (more readable) in the context - just one `Where`, -  not "better"

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use the Replace function of the Regex:

```
string a = "ash&#<>fg  fd";
a= Regex.Replace(a, "[@&'(\\s)<>#]","");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
string1 = "12@34#adf$c5,6,7,ok"
output = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]','',string1)
```

> > > > ^ will use for except mention in brackets(or replace special char with white spaces) will substitute with whitespaces then will return in string

result = 1234adfc567ok