# Regex for including a special character

Tags: c#

I have requirement to remove all the special characters from any string except " and ' .

```
ClientName = Regex.Replace(ClientName, @"\(.*?\)", " ").Trim();
```

This is the regex I am using. I want exclude all the special characters except " and '.

Example:

```
clientName= "S"unny, Cool. Mr"
```

Output should be

```
"S"unny Cool Mr"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for removing only specific special characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045115/regex-for-removing-only-specific-special-characters-from-string), the answer is the same, just include the one's you *want* to remove.

Comment: If you don't want to use `Regex` you could always use `string.Replace / string.Remove`, just a thought.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special" character so that's a bad search term. You need to explicitly define what you want included in the output. You appear to want letters, whitespace, single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the following pattern:

```
@"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}'""\s]+"
```

This will target all special characters while also excluding single and double quote, as well as whitespace.

```
string clientName = "S\"unny, Cool. Mr";
string output = Regex.Replace(clientName, @"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}'""]+", "");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This prints:

```
S"unny Cool Mr
```

The character classes `\p{L}` and `\p{N}` represent all Unicode letters and numbers, so placing them into a negative character class means remove anything which is *not* a number or letter.